# POST request with RequestBody is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

in the below example, i am using POST and GET methods. post is to initialize a varibale and GET is to get this varibale.
I use Postman to make the requests.

i am receiving an error

```
@RequestBody(value = "val") //cant resolve method value
```

please let me know how to fix the belwo error so i can use post method for initialization and get methdo to retrieve the value

**Controller1**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/call1")
public class Call1 {

public String str = "inti";

@RequestMapping(value = "/intiparam1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void intiParam1(@RequestBody(value = "val") String val) {
    this.str = val;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getparam1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getParam1() {
    return this.str;
}
}
```

Comment: `RequestBody` doesn't have a `value` method, it shouldn't be used on a method, but on a parameter. [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) and a [short tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class Variable and use other code in controller.

```
class Variable {

String data= 'val';
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/intiparam1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void intiParam1(@RequestBody Variable val) {
    this.str = val.data;
}
```

When making a request pass json as {"data":"12345"}

and then use @RequestBody Variable v in code instead of String as it will serve your purpose of default value and will make the code extensible as you can add different properties to the existing variable in future if needed.

Comment: would you please provide some code as i cant find a relation between v and class you implemented

Answer (score 1):

*When to use `@RequestBody`?*

*You can not use value with it*. You can use this when you have multiple field entity which you want to perform the operation. Let's say you want to save the user then you may need to create User Model first and use in a controller `@RequestBody`.

Model:

```
public class User
{
   @Id
   private int id;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   //Getters-Setters, AllArgConstructor-constructor
}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestBodyExample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String intiParam1(@RequestBody User user) {
     return user.getFirstname();
}
```

[Quick Start with Spring Boot](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest-api-example/)