# How to write request for POST operation with responseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in the below example, i am trying to initialize a varibale via POST and GET request as shown below below. fro POST request i want to post for example 1332
so when i do GET request i should get the same number 1332

now when the app runs for the post request, i receive an error from postman

```
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required request body is missing: public void com.example.callwithparameters.controller.Call1.initparam1(java.lang.String)",
```

please let me know how to fix this error and perform a correct POST request

**Controller1**

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/call1")
public class Call1 {

public String str = "inti";

@RequestMapping(value = "/initparam1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void initparam1(@RequestBody String val) {
    this.str = val;
}

@RequestMapping("/getparam1")
public String getParam1() {
    return this.str;
}
}
```

**post_request_postman**

```
http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?1332
result:"error"
```

**get_request_postman**

```
http://localhost:8085/call1/getparam1

result:init
```

Comment: error messages i clear you are not passing post body, if you want `RequestBody` as optional set like this `public void initparam1(@RequestBody(required=false) String val) {`

Comment: Try `curl -X POST -d '1332' http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1`.

Comment: as i told you in this, first try to learn difference between `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021251/post-request-with-requestbody-is-not-working/57021463#57021463

Answer (score 0):

In your URL you are passing your string as a `Query` or `URL` parameter, not in `RequestBody`
    http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?1332

So, Either change `@RequestBody` to `@RequestParam("str")` and make request like:

```
http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?str=1332
```

**OR** 
Pass It in request body

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you have to change your request type to "POST". You can specify body type as "RAW" data and provide your value as body.